# WoW Macro - Placing skills on special bars

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to make a macro where every time I click on it, I'm placing a different spell.
I want to do it on the "MultiCastSummonSpellButton" (It's for a shaman, so this will actually toggle between the 3 spells "Call of the Elements", "Call of the Ancestors" and the third).
I couldn't find the ID of the Button nor any other way to make it happen.

Would very much appreciate some ideas/help.
Thank you.

Comment: Not that you can't/shouldn't ask that here, but maybe ask on gaming.stackexchange.com as well

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know. I will try to check out gaming.stackexchange.com. To delete the question here then?

Comment: Nah, probably leave it up here too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but wouldn't 
[/castsequence](https://wowpedia.org/MACRO_castsequence) suffice here?

Comment: /castsequence lets me cast a different spell every click of the macro. What I want is different: The goal is to have 12 skills binded to 4 keys. I want with every click of the macro to switch between "Call of the Element", "Call of the ancestors" and the last, so that it will change the 4 skills of my earth, fire, water and earth totems, and then my bindings on the same button will refer to a different skill every time. I hope I explained to more clearly this time. Thank you for the respond.